# How to integrate Google calendar scheduler into my ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, google-calendar-api

How to create calendar scheduler (task) like Google calendar in my ASP.NET application? Please try to help me.

I am trying on jQuery but I am not that much expert in jQuery. Please try to give me solution for this. I want to create schedule for my customer and store it in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Lite version of [Day Pilot](http://www.daypilot.org/) , as for Google Calendar you just can embed in iFrame but you won't be able to save any of the events in your database.

Comment: But i want customize that as per my requirement..And store those schedules in Databse for reporting purpose

Comment: Daypilot is customizable, try it. u think looking 5 minute onto webpage and screenshots will be decision maker? Put them into code and use it to learn more

Answer (score 1):

There's one [dot net guide to use Google Calendars](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html) in asp.net using C# refer to that.

EDIT:

There are Events in google calendar which you can create using C# coding and while executing the events you save the data in database.

Comment: is it saves data in my database?

Comment: @user581007, refer to the Edited post now